# Parse html from JSON file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get HTML tags to work in my json-file that i fetch via js.

So i want the return to somehow make the `<strong>` to work when render it on the page. How would i do that?

Sample of the json:

```
{
    "header_title": "<strong>test</strong>"
}
```

JS:

```
const newTranslations = await fetchTranslationsFor(
    newLocale,
);

async function fetchTranslationsFor(newLocale) {
    const response = await fetch('/lang/en.json');
    return await response.json();
}
```

To render it i do like so: pseudo.

```
element.innerText = json.myprop;
```

Comment: How have you attempted to render it on the page?

Comment: If you do `something.innerHTML = newTranslations.header_title` you should see it rendered (`something` is a variable containing the element you want to display it in).

Comment: What's the question here? You have a working solution based on the code you've provided

Comment: How i make the html tags in the json to display as html and not plain strings.

Comment: Where/when is your rendering code called? What does your html look like? What is `element`? What is `json`? Be sure to read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Problem solved. Changes innerText to innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `innerText` to `innerHTML`. When you use the text method, it escapes the html characters. Innerhtml renders the exact html.

```js
element.innerHTML = json.myprop;
```